# Validations in SignUp page (Android system)

Tags: java, android, json, eclipse

I'm trying to create a Sign Up page for my Android system. I need to check validations for it like email_id already exists ,password should contain more than eight characters ,mobile number field should contain maximum 10 digits .How can I do it?? This is my code..I use java rest webservices and Mysql database

Sign Up.java

```
package com.example.locationapp;

import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.content.SharedPreferences.Editor;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;

@SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
public class SignUp extends Activity {

    EditText et_name, et_email, et_password, et_conf_password, et_number;
    Button signup;
    private Context context;
    private ProgressDialog pDialog;
    private CheckInternet checkNet;
    private Pattern pattern;
    private Matcher matcher;

    private String EMAIL_PATTERN, name, email, password, conf_password, number,
            toastMessage;
    private boolean emailValidity, internet_status;

    private final String TAG_RESPONSE_CODE = "resp_code";

    ServiceHandle jsonParser = new ServiceHandle();

    private String url = "http://172.30.54.89:8080/LocationBasedFramework/SignUp/RegisterUser";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

        context = SignUp.this;
        et_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.nameEditText);
        et_email = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.emailEditText);
        et_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.passwordEditText);
        et_conf_password = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.conf_passwordEditText);
        et_number = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.numberEditText);

        signup = (Button) findViewById(R.id.signUpbutton);
        checkNet = new CheckInternet();
        EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
                + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

        pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(SignUp.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("New User...");

        signup.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // CheckInternet
                name = et_name.getText().toString();
                email = et_email.getText().toString();
                password = et_password.getText().toString();
                conf_password = et_conf_password.getText().toString();
                number = et_number.getText().toString();

                if (email.equals("")) {

                    toastMessage = "Email field cannot be empty";

                    et_email.requestFocus(1);
                } else {

                    emailValidity = validate(email);

                    if (!emailValidity) {

                        toastMessage = "Invalid E_mail id";
                        et_email.setText("");
                        checkNet.ToastMessage(toastMessage,
                                getApplicationContext());
                        System.out.println("onclick 3.5");
                        et_email.requestFocus(1);

                    } else {
                        System.out.println("-------onClick4-------");
                        if (password.equals("")) {
                            toastMessage = "Password field cannot be empty";
                            checkNet.ToastMessage(toastMessage, context);
                            et_conf_password.setText("");
                            et_password.requestFocus(1);

                        } else {

                            if (conf_password.equals("")) {
                                toastMessage = "Please confirm your password";
                                checkNet.ToastMessage(toastMessage, context);
                                et_conf_password.requestFocus(1);

                            } else {

                                if (name.equals("")) {
                                    toastMessage = "Plaese enter your name";
                                    checkNet.ToastMessage(toastMessage, context);
                                    et_name.requestFocus(1);

                                } else {

                                    if (number.equals("")) {
                                        toastMessage = "Mobile No field cannot be empty";
                                        checkNet.ToastMessage(toastMessage,
                                                context);
                                        et_number.requestFocus(1);

                                    } else {
                                        System.out
                                                .println("-------onClick8-------");
                                        internet_status = checkNet
                                                .isInternetOn(context);
                                        if (internet_status == true) {
                                            System.out
                                                    .println("-------onClick9-------");
                                            new CreateUser().execute();

                                        } else {
                                            System.out
                                                    .println("-------onClick10-------");
                                            checkNet.ifNoInternet(context);

                                        }

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }

            }
        });
    }

    public boolean validate(String email) {

        CharSequence hex = null;
        matcher = pattern.matcher(email);

        return matcher.matches();

    }

    class CreateUser extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

        StringEntity se = null;
        JSONObject json;
        String jsonStr = "";

        Boolean failure = false;

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {

            super.onPreExecute();

            pDialog.show();

        }

        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            try {

                json = new JSONObject();
                json.put("name", name);
                json.put("email_id", email);
                json.put("password", password);
                json.put("mob_num", number);

                se = new StringEntity(json.toString());
                System.out.println("--after se--");
                String method = "post";

                // int response_flag = 1;
                ServiceHandle sh = new ServiceHandle();
                internet_status = checkNet
                        .isInternetOn(getApplicationContext());
                System.out.println("--internet--" + internet_status);
                if (internet_status == true) {
                    jsonStr = sh.makeServiceCall(url, method, se);

                } else {
                    checkNet.ifNoInternet(context);

                }

                if (jsonStr != null) {
                    json = new JSONObject(jsonStr);
                    int resp_code = json.getInt(TAG_RESPONSE_CODE);
                    if (resp_code == 0) {
                        name = json.getString("TAG_Name");
                        email = json.getString("TAG_Email");
                        password = json.getString("TAG_Password");
                        conf_password = json.getString("TAG_confPassword");
                        number = json.getString("TAG_Number");

                    }

                } else {
                    ;
                }

            }

            catch (Exception e) {
            }

            return null;
        }

        protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            try {
                pDialog.cancel();

                int response_flag = 0;
                if (response_flag == 0) {
                    int resp_code = 0;
                    if (resp_code == 0) {

                        SharedPreferences pref = getApplicationContext()
                                .getSharedPreferences("userData", MODE_PRIVATE);
                        Editor editor = pref.edit();
                        editor.clear();
                        editor.commit();
                        editor.putString("name", name);
                        editor.putString("e_mail", email);
                        editor.putString("password", password);
                        editor.putString("conf_password", conf_password);
                        editor.putString("number", number);
                        editor.commit();
                        Intent intent = new Intent(SignUp.this, ViewMap.class);
                        startActivity(intent);
                        finish();

                    }
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {

            }
        }

    }

}
```

This is the xml for SignUp.java .

```
activity_sign_up.xml

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.locationapp.SignUp" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/NametextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="50dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Name"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/emailtextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="100dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Email-id"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/passwordtextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="150dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Password"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

     <TextView
         android:id="@+id/conf_passwordtextView"
         android:layout_width="wrap_content"
         android:layout_height="wrap_content"
         android:layout_marginTop="200dp"
         android:gravity="center"
         android:text="Confirm Password"
         android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/numbertextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="250dp"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Mobile"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/nameEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/NametextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/NametextView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/passwordtextView"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/emailEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/emailtextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/emailtextView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/passwordtextView"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:ems="10" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/passwordEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/passwordtextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/passwordtextView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/passwordtextView"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword" />

     <EditText
        android:id="@+id/conf_passwordEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/conf_passwordtextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/passwordtextView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/conf_passwordtextView"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textPassword"/>

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/numberEditText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/numbertextView"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/numbertextView"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/passwordtextView"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="number" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/signUpbutton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/numbertextView"
        android:layout_marginTop="34dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/emailtextView"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="SIGNUP" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: get text from edittext and apply validation as per your requirement

Answer (score 1):

**To check validations for it like email_id already exists**
...Manage it form server

**password should contain more than eight characters ,mobile number field should contain maximum 10 digits**

Just pass password to following given mathod

private boolean isValidEmail(String email) {

```
    String EMAIL_PATTERN = "^[_A-Za-z0-9-\\+]+(\\.[_A-Za-z0-9-]+)*@"
            + "[A-Za-z0-9-]+(\\.[A-Za-z0-9]+)*(\\.[A-Za-z]{2,})$";

    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(EMAIL_PATTERN);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(email);
    return matcher.matches();
}
```